Count the number of users following a ticker in django
I need to get the top stock tickers followed by users, the issue is when two users or more follow the same ticker, it get repeated when using the query Tickers.objects.annotate(followers=Count('users')).order_by('followers') as shown here:

In this example, the ticker FDCFF needs to be the top ticker since two users are following it, instead it gets repeated and its not being shown as the top followed ticker.
Update: the number of followers for FDCFF should be 2 but I get the ticker listed twice instead.
Models.py
class Tickers(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='tickers')

views.py
def index(request):
    tickers = Tickers.objects.annotate(followers=Count('users')).order_by('followers')
    context = {
    'tickers': tickers,
    }
    return render(request, 'main_index.html', context=context)

template
{% for ticker in tickers.all|slice:'10' %}
        <tr>
          <td class=''>
            <a href="{% url 'Symbol:index' ticker=ticker.symbol %}">{{ticker.symbol}}</a>
            <span>{{ticker.name}}</span>
          </td>
          </tr>
{% endfor %}


You should order in descending order, so -followers, not followers:
def index(request):
    tickers = Tickers.objects.annotate(followers=Count('users')).order_by(
        '-followers'
    )
    context = {
        'tickers': tickers,
    }
    return render(request, 'main_index.html', context=context)

I am not getting the users count for each ticker, it does not matter if its ascending or descending if the number of followers for each ticker is not being counted.

What if you use {{ ticker.followers }}?

ticker.followers. The ticker FDCFF should be counted as 2
